# Failure to run pmml to java using command prompt

Tags: java, cmd, pmml

I've been trying to run a pmml file into java but I'm starting by doing it in command prompt. Installing the maven correctly with the correct file path and following this guide/API:

> https://github.com/jpmml/jpmml-evaluator/blob/master/README.md#basic-usage

I followed the **Example Applications** part of the document with the code:

> java -cp target/pmml-evaluator-executable-1.4-SNAPSHOT.jar
>   org.jpmml.evaluator.EvaluationExample --model model.pmml --input
>   input.csv --output output.csv

after running it, it gave an error message:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected unique cell names, got non-unique cell name(s)

may I know what are the possible ways to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This exception means that your input file `input.csv` contains duplicate columns. The JPMML-Evaluator example application does not know which column to use.